# Rename Document Set through code

Tags: document-library, document, document-set

I have placed a web part on the welcome screen of a document set.  When i click the button i want to be able to rename the document set.

Has anyone accomplished this?

I can get reference to the current document set via
      SPListItem item = SPContext.Current.ListItem;
      DocumentSet set = DocumentSet.GetDocumentSet(item.Folder);

//document set name
set.Item["Name"] = "new name";
set.Item.Update();

the above couple lines seems to do something but i get an exception about not able to open folder

any ideas?
ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that as the DocumentSet object derives from SPFolder,

you should use the same method to rename a folder than a document set

so something like

```
set.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = newDsName;
set.Item.Update(); //or SystemUpdate(false)
```

or

you could use the MoveTo Method on the SPFolder Object